Significance of the Year of the Flood?
I've been studying how the biblical creation & re-creation in Genesis, from Adam to Noah, foreshadows the Exodus.
For instance, Noah is of the 10th generation of mankind. The Hebrews were slaves in Egypt for 400 years = 40 x 10 = 10 generations if we assume 40 years per generation. 10 generations of the righteous line appears to represent a certain fullness of time, after which God enacts judgement.
Anyways, what I am interested in for this post is the year of the flood (beginning and/or end) and the significance thereof. Genesis is careful to document what year each person was born in, in terms of the age of their father, up through and including Noah. It also tells us that the flood began in Noah's 600th year - and even specifies the month and day.
From my calculations, it looks like the flood began in the year 1656 (from creation) and ended in 1657 (from creation). Off hand, I don't see the significance of either number. Yet, why would the author of Genesis be so specific about these dates if there were no meaning to it? Please share your insights :)

Chazal says Moshe had to deduce the shabbat as it was forgotten when they were about to leave mitzraim.may be this could be ome significance

@RakhemHaokip oh that's an interesting idea :)

You can also add , in order to prove the validity of the Torah that it's not made up
